# In android,can static anonymous inner class be passed as serializable?

Tags: android

```
static interface A extends Serializable{void a();}
```

---

```
Intent it = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, c); 
it.putExtra("simplekey", new A(){
                @Override
                public void a() {

                }

            });
startActivity(it);
```

This throws an `IOexception`:

```
not serializable object(XX.XXXAcitivty$1$1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't, because you can't declare an anonymous inner class as static in the first place.

Declaring an interface as static does not make a class that implements it static, because the static keyword is completely redundant when applied to an interface, as an interface cannot be instantiated. You can think of all interface declarations as implicitly containing the static keyword. So in the example above you are passing a non-static anonymous inner class.

However, you can declare a static inner class and pass it as Serializable, like this:

```
// this static keyword doesn't make any difference:
static interface A extends Serializable{void a();}
// this static keyword DOES make a difference:
static class B implements A
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;            
    @Override
    public void a() {

    }
}
```

and

```
Intent it = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, c); 
it.putExtra("simplekey", new B());
startActivity(it);
```

B is a static class, and it extends Serializable, so there is no error. The anonymous inner class `A(){public void a()}` is not static, and so even though it extends Serializable it will cause an error, because it will have a reference to the outer class that can't be serialized.

Comment: A extends Serializable interface,but the anonymous inner class(A) can' be pass as serializable object.Do u konw the reason?I know the B can be passed.

Comment: Because B is static and the anonymous inner class A isn't. Declaring the interface as static doesn't make a difference.